# Drag and drop from VirtualTreeView to shell (Ole drag and drop)

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, c++builder, ole, virtualtreeview

I am trying to drag and drop from `VirtualTreeView` to create a file in shell (drag and drop from `VirtualTreeView` to a folder in File Explorer or desktop folder).

I only found example of doing the opposite (shell to VirtualTreeView), but I cannot find any example for doing that. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing any drag-drop operations in Windows involves creating an `IDataObject`, and giving that object to Windows.

The Virtual Treeview handles a lot of that grunt-work for you, creating an object that implements `IDataObject` for you. The tree then raises events when you need to help populate it.

When passing *"file-like"* things through a copy-paste or a drag-drop, you are require to add two clipboard formats to the `IDataObject`:

- `CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR`, and
- `CF_FILECONTENTS`

In addition to support for formats that the virtualtree itself will add, you can choose to indicate support for more clipboard format.

### OnGetUserClipboardFormats Event

This is the event where you are given a chance to add additional clipboard formats to the `IDataObject` that the tree will be creating:

```
procedure TForm1.lvAttachmentsGetUserClipboardFormats(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  var Formats: TFormatEtcArray);
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    //Add formats for CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR and CF_FILECONTENTS
    i := Length(Formats);
    SetLength(Formats, i + 1);
    Formats[i].cfFormat := CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR;
    Formats[i].ptd := nil;
    Formats[i].dwAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
    Formats[i].lindex := -1;
    Formats[i].tymed := TYMED_HGLOBAL;

    i := Length(Formats);
    SetLength(Formats, i + 1);
    Formats[i].cfFormat := CF_FILECONTENTS;
    Formats[i].ptd := nil;
    Formats[i].dwAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
    Formats[i].lindex := 0;
    Formats[i].tymed := TYMED_ISTREAM;
end;
```

The tree will then given the `IDataObject` to the shell as part of the drag-drop operation.

Later, an application that the user dropped items onto will enumerate all formats in the `IDataObject`, e.g.:

- `CF_HTML` *("HTML Format")*
- `CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR` *("FileGroupDescriptorW")*
- `CFSTR_FILECONTENTS` *("FileContents")*
- `CF_ENHMETAFILE`

And it will see that the `IDataObject` contains **FileDescriptor** and **FileContents**.

The receiving application will then ask the `IDataObject` to actually cough up data. (This *"delayed-rendering"* is a good thing, it means your source application doesn't actually have to read any content unless it actually gets requested).

### OnRenderOleData Event

This is the event where the virtual tree realizes its `IDataObject` has been asked to render something, and it needs you to finally render that actual content.

The general idea with these two clipboard formats is:

- `CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR` lets you return a record that describes the file-like thing (e.g. filename, file size, created date, last modified date, last accessed date)
- `CF_FILECONTENTS` lets you return an `IStream` that contains the actual file contents

```
procedure TForm1.lvAttachmentsRenderOLEData(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; const FormatEtcIn: tagFORMATETC;
  out Medium: tagSTGMEDIUM; ForClipboard: Boolean; var Result: HRESULT);
var
    global: HGLOBAL;
    stm: IStream;
begin
    if FormatEtcIn.cfFormat = CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR then
    begin
        global := GetAttachmentFileDescriptorsFromListView(lvAttachments, ForClipboard);
        if global = 0 then
            Exit;
        ZeroMemory(@Medium, SizeOf(Medium));
        Medium.tymed := TYMED_HGLOBAL;
        Medium.hGlobal := global;
        Result := S_OK;
    end
    else if FormatEtcIn.cfFormat = CF_FILECONTENTS then
    begin
        ZeroMemory(@Medium, SizeOf(Medium));
        Medium.tymed := TYMED_ISTREAM;
        Result := GetAttachmentStreamFromListView(lvAttachments, ForClipboard, FormatEtcIn.lindex, stm);
        if Failed(Result) then
            Exit;
        Medium.stm := Pointer(stm);
        IUnknown(Medium.stm)._AddRef;
        Result := S_OK;
    end;
end;
```

The first helper function creates an array of `FILE_DESCRIPTOR` objects, and copies them to a `HGLOBAL` allocated memory:

```
function GetAttachmentFileDescriptorsFromListView(Source: TVirtualStringTree; ForClipboard: Boolean): HGLOBAL;
var
    i: Integer;
    nCount: Integer;
    nodes: TNodeArray;
    descriptors: TFileDescriptorDynArray; 
    data: TAttachment;
begin
    Result := 0;

   if ForClipboard then
      nodes := Source.GetSortedCutCopySet(False)
   else
      nodes := Source.GetSortedSelection(False);

   if Length(nodes) = 0 then
      Exit;

   nCount := 0;
   for i := 0 to Length(nodes) - 1 do
   begin
        //Get the file thing from this node
        data := GetNodeDataFromNode(nodes[i]);
        if not Assigned(data) then
            Continue;

        //Increase the size of our descriptors array by one
        Inc(nCount);
        SetLength(Descriptors, nCount);

        //Fill in the next descriptor
        descriptors[nCount-1] := data.ToWindowsFileDescriptor;
   end;

   Result := FileDescriptorsToHGLOBAL(descriptors);
end;
```

The second helper copies your file-like thing's binary contents to an `IStream`:

```
function GetAttachmentStreamFromListView(Source: TVirtualStringTree; ForClipboard: Boolean; lindex: Integer; var stm: IStream): HResult;
var
    nodes: TNodeArray;
    data: TAttachment;
begin
   Result := E_FAIL;

   if ForClipboard then
      nodes := Source.GetSortedCutCopySet(False)
   else
      nodes := Source.GetSortedSelection(False);

   if Length(nodes) = 0 then
      Exit;

   if (lIndex < Low(Nodes)) or (lIndex > High(Nodes)) then
    begin
      Result := DV_E_LINDEX;
      Exit;
   end;

   //Get the file thing from this node
   data := GetNodeDataFromNode(nodes[i]);
   if not Assigned(data) then
      Continue;

    //Fetch the content into a IStream wrapped memory stream
    stm := data.GetStream(nil);
    Result := S_OK;
end;
```

Your attachment object, whatever it is has to know:

- how to represent itself as a `TFileDescriptor`
- how to return the contents as an `IStream`

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer with useful code example! I have a further question though  - where I can detect if the drag-N-drop is a "move" or "copy" operation, which in case it's a "move", so that I can remove the source data?

Comment: @EdwinYip You ask the `IDataObject` for it's `CF_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT` (*perferred*) format, which contains a `DWORD` which can be (among other things): `DROPEFFECT_COPY`, `DROPEFFECT_MOVE`. Once you've performed the transfer, be sure to tell the caller if you **actually** moved or copied it by setting the `CF_PERFORMEDDROPEFFECT` (*performed*). See [Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](https://archive.ph/gL8O7) for more information.

Comment: thanks, that's from the receiver's perspective, and it's helpful. I also need to know the opposite -  from the source (the virtual treeview)'s perspective, where and how to know what action (move or copy) has taken? Is it in `OnRenderOLEData`? I checked the parameters of that event and could't figure out...

Comment: @EdwinYip In the Windows Shell model, the source knows you've set the `CF_PERFORMEDDROPEFFECT` because you call the **SetData** method on **their** object. So their implementation of **SetData** checks if you're setting the *performed drop effect*, and uses that to decide if it needs to delete the database because of a move.

Comment: Actually in the case of my question above, the source is our Virtual Treeview ;) Actually I'm wanting something like `TVirtualStringTree.OnDropFinsihedOnTheOtherSide` which has a parameter called something like `ActionTaken`...

Comment: @EdwinYip Yeah, i knew what you wanted; but i couldn't remember off the top of my head, so i sorta did some hand-waving there. But the answer is: *no*. I searched every `.pas` file on my PC, and nowhere does anyone (including VCL or Virtual Trees) even reference `CFSTR_PERFORMEDDROPEFFECT`.

Comment: Thanks for the further reply. I came up with a workaround - to provide an interface of the dragging source to the drop target so that the drop target can call back the source about the further operation, using the `IDataObject`, something like `IDragSourceForm.DropFinished(aActionTaken)`. I works because in my case it's not cross-process dragging.